# Set a custom homepath for Mongo in Win 10

Tags: windows, mongodb

I installed Mongo on my machine (installed in the Program Files folder), setting up the data and log destinations on another drive.

Upon exit from the Mongo shell, it wants to write the .dbshell file to my User profile folder (C:\Users\Name.dbshell). **This process fails, because my username contains diacritic characters, which the Mongo shell parses incorrectly.** This throws the following error:

```
Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed Unable to fopen() file C:\Users\Name and Surname\.dbshell: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Can I change the Environment variables of the Mongo application? I've looked in the configuration file and there does not seem to be the appropriate option listed in the comment lines. I haven't been able to find the answer at the [configuration page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) as of yet. I looked at the [mongo reference page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#envvar-HOMEDRIVE) and while it does mention the Environment variables and associated commands, using these does not seem to do anything and running a Mongo shell will still throw an error upon exit because of incorrect parsing of the path.

**My question, then, is, how can I change the default path to which Mongo will write its .dbshell file?**

Comment: Try `SET HOMEPATH=C:\folder of your choice` (or/and `SET USERPROFILE=...`) before your start the mongo shell.

Comment: Thank you Wernfried! But won't that change the homepath/userprofile path for all the applications? Or is it limited to just that powershell session?

Comment: I think from command line it is valid only in the current process and child processes.

Comment: I tried it. Setting any of the parameters doesn't do anything or at least doesn't have the effect on the mongo shell, as I still keep getting the same error message. Have you been able to change the default paths in this way?

Comment: No, it was just an assumption. What is your username? Maybe change to codepage of your shell.